# Operator<< doesn't return object contents

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have an assignment where I am tasked with creating a program to construct doubly linked list to hold very long integers. One of the tasks to to create a method for operator+ overloading to add two very long int objects. When I try user the operator<< method to print out single objects it works great and what I expect is printed out. But when I add two objects nothing is printed out... it's as if my object is lost. Can anyone help me debug this? Why is my LongInt object not being printed out to console after calling the operator+ method?

Issue is a+b returns blank:
[image]

```
// Arithmetic Binary Operator +
// Adds two LongInt objects
// Input: a LongInt object
// Output: a new LongInt which is the sum of lhs (current) and rhs (argument)
LongInt LongInt::operator+( const LongInt &rhs ){
    Deque<char> lhs = digits;
    Deque<char> rhs2 = rhs.digits;
    Deque<char> newLongInt;

    int carry = 0;
    while (!lhs.isEmpty() && !rhs2.isEmpty()){
        newLongInt.addFront((lhs.getBack()+rhs2.getBack() + carry) % 10);
        carry = (lhs.removeBack() + rhs2.removeBack()) / 10;
    }
    LongInt test;
    test.digits = newLongInt;
    return test;
}

// Prints LongInt to console
// Input: Reference to LongInt
// Output: string of LongInt printed out
ostream &operator<<( ostream &out, const LongInt &rhs ) {
    // check if LongInt is negative and if so, add '-'
    rhs.negative == true ? out << "-" : out << "";

    // temp deque<char>
    Deque<char> temp = rhs.digits;

    // check if it is empty
    if (temp.isEmpty()) {
        out << "0";
    } else {
        // loop through linked list then output LongInt
        while(!temp.isEmpty()){
            out << temp.removeFront();
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Please form a [repro] of your problem. We don't know how `LongInt` is defined, `Deque<char>` is not a standard library type either and we don't see how you use the methods or how you print the results. There is not enough context here.

Comment: Having side-effects (such as printing) at the `?:` operator is weird, bad style, and a good way to create bugs `rhs.negative == true ? out << "-" : out << "";` (Not related to the bug in question). Better to use a regular `if` statement

Comment: @MichaelVeksler Adding to that: `out << rhs.negative ? "-" : "";` is shorter and clearer and does the same thing, if you don't want to use an `if` statement.

Comment: It's likely that either the while loop never terminates (in your `operator<<`), or the stream entered a bad state. A stream in a bad state prints nothing, unless `out.clear()` is called. You should find what sets it in bad state.

Comment: Too little information. Probably unrelated to your problem, but why are you copying the whole deck just to print it? Seems very wrong.

Comment: Not an answer, but `carry = (lhs.removeBack() + rhs2.removeBack() + carry) / 10;`